# Qt customize the rectangle boundaries to get mild 3D effect

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

Could you please tell me how can I draw rectangles with boundaries like [this](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/OEQi97Px95bBY1V4ftUc5dMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink), by custom QGraphicsItem. I did the layout and drawn the rectangles, but the boundaries of my [rectangles](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/64ZKg-68ZBlrq-l22QJhqtMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink) are plain pen. Request your help. Thanks.

```
void QGraphicsTileItem::paint(QPainter *painter,
                              const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                              QWidget *widget)
{
    /// Draw the rect
    painter->setRenderHints( QPainter::Antialiasing |
                             QPainter::TextAntialiasing |
                             QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform |
                             QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing, true );
    painter->setPen( pen );
    painter->setBrush( colour );
    painter->drawRect( bound );
    painter->drawText( bound, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop |
                       Qt::TextSingleLine, name );
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't draw rectangles. I would draw 2 sets of lines.

Comment: Do what @Sosukodo says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a paintEvent from a QWidget. You should be able to adapt it to your paint event (you would use your bound varible instead of "this"):

```
void Button::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter paint;
    paint.begin(this);
    paint.setPen(Qt::white);
    paint.drawLine(0,0, this->width(), 0);
    paint.drawLine(0,0, 0, this->height());
    paint.setPen(Qt::black);
    paint.drawLine(0, this->height()-1, this->width()-1, this->height()-1);
    paint.drawLine(this->width()-1, 0, this->width()-1, this->height()-1);
    paint.end();
}
```

Comment: [This][1] is what I am getting now, thanks for that. But it is not exactly what I am trying to achieve. Any suggestions please. 


  [1] https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/NwC_3WCZY01w1gztYlu0C9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Comment: Well this solution works fine with little tweaking . Thanks very much for your help.